# ms access table relationships - where clause

Tags: ms-access, join, database-design, table-relationships

I have two tables that I'm trying to create a relationship for.

```
Table_A:
ID_A
Flag (Y/N)

Table_B:
ID_A
ID_B
```

The two tables link on `ID_A`, where `Table_A.Flag='Y'`

Is there a way to define the relationship in this way?

**Clarification:**
I am using the fact that it can be done in SQL as the basis for my question--how would I translate this into a ms-access table relationship?

Comment: It's easy with SQL.  Not sure about MS Access, because it tries to hide the fact that it's SQL from you.  Your WHERE has an AND: A.ID_A = B.ID_A and A.Flag = 'Y'.  Take "Table" out of the table name.  It's redundant, no information.  What else would it be?

Comment: I know that you can do it with SQL Thanks though.

Comment: @duffymo not sure how the comments about table naming help the poster. Using "Table" in the example names made it very easy to read, even if it's not a best practice in produciton.

Comment: What else would it be?  This is SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is certainly possible when constructing Queries in MS Access, as far as I'm aware, it isn't possible to define a Table Relationship as anything more advanced than either an `INNER` or (`RIGHT/LEFT`) `OUTER` join, with or without Referential Integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Access (JET) SQL will not let you join on a condition like you can in other variants such as T-SQL. So you can't do the following:

```
    ON a.ID = b.ID
   AND Flag = 'y'
```

The way I'd probably solve this problem in Access-SQL would be to create a subquery by editing the SQL like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE Flag = 'y') a
 INNER JOIN Table_B b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Or else by materializing the "SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE Flag = 'y'" as an Access query and joining to it.